# ./node_modules/ng2-completer/esm5/ng2-completer.js Module not found: Error

Tags: angular6, ng2-smart-table

smartTable it shows below error after doing necessary `npm` installation

> ./node_modules/ng2-completer/esm5/ng2-completer.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'C:\POC\projectMgnt\node_modules\ng2-completer\esm5'

However I can see `esm5` folder with `ng2-completer.js`

Answer (score 0):

Run these two commands in your project directory. Error solved in my case.

```
npm i rxjs-compat --save
npm i ng2-completer --save
```